# cloth sim phantom collision

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image: cloth-sim]

I have a basic scene with 1 collision plane that sits under 3 cloth soft bodies, animated for 50 frames. It looks like the top plane collides at frame 14 with the 2 spheres where they were located in frame 1.

Things I've tried:

- Bake All Dynamics
- With and without cache of the same name
- In-memory vs On Disk Cache
- Order of the Collision + Cloth modifiers
- With and without a Collision Collection

The scale of the items are: plane (4m x 2m x 0.05m), spheres (0.3m radius). This is a brand new scene and default settings. I've adjusted the collision distances to be more accurate and used loop cut on the plane to give it some basic cloth shape as it collides. Otherwise, nothing weird or unusual.

Blender 3.6.2.

Comment: Put the Soft Body modifier above the Collisions modifiers in the modifier stack of your balls? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Answer (score 0):

Put the *Soft Body* modifier above the *Collisions* modifiers in the modifier stack of your balls:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having both a Collision modifier and a Cloth modifier on an object can cause this behavior. Removing the Collision modifier and only using the Cloth modifier resolves this issue.